# Get image from URL - Power Apps

Tags: image, url, powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

I'm building a simple app, which shows news from different websites, e.g. https://techcrunch.com/2020/07/28/transferwise-five-unicorns/

My source is a database with news URLs.

Each article comes with an associated image. I do not have a URL of the image, only URL of news itself.

My question is, how can I get the associated image to appear in my Gallery? Is there a function I could use?
[image]

Here is an effect I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Help please,

Thanks!

Maciej

Ps. I know it is possible, as all rss readers (like Feedly) or even SharePoint news webpart easily pull image just from provided link.. but how?

Answer (score 0):

Are you unable to copy the image path and manually input it into where you want it to go?

Comment: Technically I could copy the image URL for each article and paste it in power apps, but there are thousands of news plus new ones coming in live so the point is to have the application grab the image automatically.

Comment: Okay, so I have figured out where to find a URL of the image. It is in the metadata of each news website, looks like this:

<meta property="og:image" content="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/GettyImages-1084518636.jpg?w=764">

Is there a function / formula that could look for this property on the website and return the link??